# Magento 2 to Magento 2 theme migration

Tags: magento2, theme

We have two instances of Magento 2.2.4:

**Site 1**
With porto theme and a lot of customisation.

**Site 2**
No theme installed.

We have purchased porto theme once again for the second site. 
Is there a way to get all the customisation from site 1 to site 2 easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to copy over the theme itself. The theme is installed in the `app/design/frontend`, then under the namespace of the theme so in your case something along the lines of `app/design/frontend/Porto/default`. To copy the theme to you new site you simply need to copy that directory over to your second codebase.

Some 3rd party themes also come with a complementary modules, they would be under `app/code/{vendor namespace}`. I am not sure if porto does that but if that was the case they would also need to be copied over to your second codebase.

<s>Of course if you have installed your theme with composer it will be even easier. Just run `composer require vendor/package` from command line in your new project</s>. If you have modified the theme directly you won't be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks Andrew,  

I did that but I am getting this exception when I load the front page  

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'about-us' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 710